# ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built

Tags: ios, xcode, rubymotion

I am trying to submit my first ruby motion application via apple application loader and I get the error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently
>   accepting applications built with this version of the SDK." at
>   SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I have set my deployment target to '7.0' and my SDK_version to '7.0' in my rake file. I have tried updating Xcode, removing and reinstalling it.

I believe the latest versions of Xcode comes with SDK 7.0.3. My iOS SDK version is 7.0, I can confirm from inspecting the Xcode package contents. I can also see from my compiled app that the iphoneos SDK is being set to '7.0' - any ideas why the app should still fail using this SDK?

I've spend 5 hours online and there is no relevant solution to these versions. Could it be some other issue with my rake file? Is anyone else experiencing this? Thanks

Using:

1. mac air 10.8.5
2. xcode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)
3. Application loader Version 2.9 (439)
4. Rubymotion 2.20

I am about the throw away 250 hours of development time. I have started a support ticket with apple and Rubymotion also.

**UPDATE**
**I have just received a reply from Rubymotion**, Laurent and Joffrey were very quick in responding and they fixed my problem. I had to add the following line to my rake file:

```
app.info_plist['DTSDKBuild'] = app.info_plist['DTPlatformBuild'] = '11B508'.
```

This is what they said the problem was " The problem is likely in the RubyMotion build system where we generate the Info.plist key. It looks like we emit the wrong value when targeting the 7.0 SDK (we emit the value for 6.0) which could totally explain why the application loader refuses the app, since Apple only accepts apps built for 7.0 now."

This is the first time they know of this to happen. will be fixed in ruby motion soon. Thanks to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else running into this, upgrade to RubyMotion 2.21, which fixed this:

> - Fixed a bug where incorrect SDK version values were being used in the
>     Info.plist file resulting in iOS App Store submissions being rejected.

Comment: hi Dylan what SDK version changes you have made in Info.plist